# Remove left & right padding from ListTile in landscape

Tags: dart, flutter

Trying to remove left and right padding from ListTile widget so the elements appear closer to the edge. I've set the property 'contentpadding' to 0 for both sides which works fine in portrait mode but when I switch to landscape the padding is still visible.  I have included a sample app below.

Copy/Paste into a new file and Run, notice in portrait view the elements with black background appear closer to edges, now switch to landscape to see the difference.  contentpadding property appears to get ignored.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(TestApp());
}

class TestApp extends StatefulWidget {
  _TestAppState createState() => new _TestAppState();

}

class _TestAppState extends State<TestApp> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(

      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: new Tester(),
    )
    ;
  }
}

class Tester extends StatefulWidget {

  Tester({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _TesterState createState() => new _TesterState();
}

class _TesterState extends State<Tester>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final TextEditingController searchQuery = new TextEditingController();
  ScrollController _scrollController;
  List<String> items;
  TabController tabContoller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    items = List<String>.generate(50, (i) => "Item $i");
    _scrollController = new ScrollController();
    tabContoller = new TabController(
      vsync: this,
      length: 1,
    );
  }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Tester"),
        ),
          body: NestedScrollView(
            controller: _scrollController,
            headerSliverBuilder:
                (BuildContext contrxt, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
              return <Widget>[];
            },

            body:
            TabBarView(
              controller: tabContoller,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Tab(
                  child: RefreshIndicator(
                    child: CustomScrollView(
                      slivers: <Widget>[
                        SliverList(
                          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                              List<Widget>.generate(50, (i) {
                                return ListTile(
                                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 0.0),
                                  title: Container(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      child: Text('${items[i]}', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)
                                  ),
                                );
                              })
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    onRefresh: () {},
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),

          ));
    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot? I'm testing on iOS simulator and it works fine

Comment: see update @diegoveloper

Comment: Maybe it's a safe area? See how the right side has a similar padding? That's interesting

Comment: I think so too, how do i fix it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like its because the `ListTile` widget wraps its content in a `SafeArea` widget which adds padding around its content. I'm assuming this is more/only noticeable on a device with a notch.

Workaround is to wrap your `ListTile` in a `MediaQuery` without padding:

```
return MediaQuery(
    data: MediaQueryData(padding: EdgeInsets.zero),
    child: ListTile(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 0.0),
        title: Container(
            color: Colors.black,
            child: Text('${items[i]}', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: What an absolute joke the default widgets in Flutter are. This worked. Thanks. Safe area needs to be left to the developer. I already took care of the safe area by putting the tab bar in the safe area. Then these widgets go ahead and add it again.

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your `Scaffold` inside `SafeArea` widget

```
  return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
        ...
```